# CloudWatch Event Rule (source S3 and target ECS task) is being triggered and its not created ECS task?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ecs, amazon-cloudwatch

I have created the cloudwatch event it contains source as S3 with PutObject and CompleteMultipartUpload and target as ECS task. My rule is working for the single file upload. But when I upload multiple files its creating only one ECS task. Is it possible to run single ECS task for each file uploads ?

```
{
  "source": [
    "aws.s3"
  ],
  "detail-type": [
    "AWS API Call via CloudTrail"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "eventSource": [
      "s3.amazonaws.com"
    ],
    "eventName": [
      "PutObject",
      "CompleteMultipartUpload"
    ],
    "requestParameters": {
      "bucketName": [
        "test"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Side question. How do you access CW Event in your ECS tasks that triggered it? You have to somehow get the details of S3 object uploaded.

Comment: Using CloudTrail API.

Comment: I mean, if you could start separate ECS task for each CW event, how would you know which S3 object should the ecs task process? The CW event is not propagated into ECS task, like it is for lambda, from what I know. Thus I ask, maybe you found a way for that?

Comment: No no. Im using same ECS task, but its needs to process single file at a time.